# Thread safe for user login limits code block

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

I have the following code (will be hit by api call to generate a access token if login succeed) to check if the user actually hit the upper limit of the login times. I am thinking use synchronized keyword for thread safe.

```
        UserDTO userDTO = null;
        synchronized (userDTO) {
            // load user info (including failed times) from db
            userDTO = userDao.findUser(username);

            if (userDTO != null) {

                // when exceeded max allowed times
                if (userDTO.getFailedLoginCount() > maxAllowed) {
                    // failed the login directly cause account locked.
                    throw new AuthenticationException(401, "Account Locked!!");
                }
                
                // if password matches, login succeed
                if (PasswordUtil.match(userDTO.getPassword(), loginInfo.getPassword())) {
                    // reset the login failure in db                         
                    userDao.resetUserLoginFailure(username);

                    return generateAccessToken(userDTO);
                }
                // update db with failed time + 1
                userDao.updateUserLoginFailure(username, userDTO.getFailedLoginCount()); 
            }
        }
        throw new AuthenticationException(401, "Invalid Login!!");
```

Comment: synchronized on a ```null``` object will cause a ```NullPointerException```

Comment: You would need to use database-level locking for this.

Comment: @TimMoore, can I get more detail or an example for this case, please?

Comment: @zysaaa, thanks for the remind. Any idea how to deal with this code block, then?

Comment: This page has a good overview: http://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-database-locking-and-the-lost-update-phenomena/ The specific details depend on the database used and the way it’s accessed from Java.